# How to set font size of NSAttributedString when converting html to string?

Tags: swift, cocoa

The idea is to to turn html parts like `<b>` from json string that contains html
At this moment I have the following code.

cell

```
cell.comment?.attributedStringValue = try! NSAttributedString(htmlString: currentPost.comment!)
```

extension

```
extension NSAttributedString {

    convenience init(htmlString html: String) throws {
        try self.init(data: Data(html.utf8), options: [
            .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
            .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
            ], documentAttributes: nil)
    }

}
```

I only found examples for ios.
I tried experimenting with the following code with no luck `NSAttributedString(string: quote, attributes: attributes)`

```
let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font:NSFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 15.0)!,
NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: NSColor.white] as! [NSAttributedStringKey: Any]
```

**UPDATE**
I rushed saying the problem was solved in the comments.
The following code updates the font and font color.
But it doesn't convert html parts into formatted text.

```
        let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font:NSFont(name: "Verdana", size: 13)!,
                          NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: NSColor.red] as [NSAttributedStringKey: Any]

        cell.comment?.attributedStringValue = try! NSAttributedString(string: currentPost.comment!, attributes: attributes)
```

Comment: While the duplicate is for iOS, it will be nearly identical for macOS. Just change `UIFont` code to `NSFont` code.

Comment: Yes, I did that. But where should I put this attributes list?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. But the post that you linked didn't really help

Comment: Il inked another duplicate that may be better.